# Cannot plot inline plotly charts in Jupyter Notebook using C#

Tags: c#, plotly, microsoft.ml, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive

Hello I am trying to plot a chart in Jupyter Notebook. I have been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mdfarragher/run-c-machine-learning-code-directly-in-a-jupyter-notebook-a32e13e40b9c).

I am using the following nuget packages to read a data and then plot it using plotly
[image]

So I have this block of code which produces a scatter plot,

```
var chart = Chart.Plot(
    new Graph.Scattergl()
    {
        x = houses.Select(v => v.Longitude),
        y = houses.Select(v => v.Latitude),
        mode = "markers",
        marker = new Graph.Marker()
        {
            color = houses.Select(v => v.MedianHouseValue),
            colorscale = "Jet"
        }
    }
);
chart.WithXTitle("Longitude");
chart.WithYTitle("Latitude");
chart.WithTitle("Median house value by location");
chart.Width = 600;
chart.Height = 600;
display(chart);
```

When I run the above cell, I get the following output,

[image]

According to the tutorial, the chart should be displayed in the output cell but I got the above output.

However, I tried to run the command `chart.Show();` instead of `dispaly(chart);` at the end, which rendered the plot in a new window. I would like to have the chart produced inline in the notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to show the plot using latest `XPlot` version and interactive ([`XPlot.Plotly.Interactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPlot.Plotly.Interactive/)) package :

```
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly"
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly.Interactive"
```

And slight code modification:

```cs
var chart = Chart.Plot(
    new Scattergl() // remove Graph.
    {
        x = houses.Select(v => v.Longitude),
        y = houses.Select(v => v.Latitude),
        mode = "markers",
        marker = new Marker() // remove Graph.
        {
            color = houses.Select(v => v.MedianHouseValue),
            colorscale = "Jet"
        }
    }
);
chart.WithXTitle("Longitude");
chart.WithYTitle("Latitude");
chart.WithTitle("Median house value by location");
chart.Width = 600;
chart.Height = 600;
chart // no display call
```

Comment: Is there a way to call .Display() on each cahrt so I can display multiple charts within a loop? @GuruStron